# Local copy of site won't load. Fatal error: Call to a member function setParent() on a non-object in lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 444

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.14

I have mirrored an EE 1.14 site to my local server to work on. I've followed my normal procedure for doing so - change base urls, modify local.xml, dump caches and session.

However, when I try to navigate to the site, or even to the magicento eval.php (/home/user_name/public_html/site_new/site/html/var/magicento/eval.php), I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setParent() on a non-object in
>   /home/user_name/public_html/site_new/site/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php
>   on line 444

Looking at the code in that area, I can see that Magento is trying to set the parent on a newly created child :

```
if (is_null($targetChild)) {
        // if child target is not found create new and descend
        $targetChild = $this->addChild($sourceName);
        $targetChild->setParent($this); //Line 444 which throws error.
        foreach ($source->attributes() as $key=>$value) {
            $targetChild->addAttribute($key, $this->xmlentities($value));
        }
    }
```

In system.log, I am getting this error :

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild.html]:
>   Element name is required  in
>   /home/user_name/public_html/site_new/site/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php
>   on line 443

So I looked back in the extendChild function a bit and added some debugging code :

```
// name of the source node
        $sourceName = $source->getName(); // Standard Magento call
       //Debug code follows :
        if(!$sourceName){ 
            echo "<pre>";
            echo print_r($source);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
```

The `if(!$sourceName)` check gets hit once per load. The output I get from the print_r is this, including the '1' at the end:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
(
    [192.168.5.112] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [~user_name] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [site_new] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                        (
                            [site] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                (
                                    [html] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
1
```

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. I've turned off rewrites, js and css compilation, set ownership to webserver:webserver, and a few different permission configurations (settled on 755/644).

Comment: I see you are using 2 different documents roots here: /var/magicento/ and the error comes from /home/user_name/public_html. I wonder how your webserver is set up? Is your /var directory writeable?

Comment: Hi Anna, actually, it's the magento_root/var folder I was referring to. Poorly worded in the original question, sorry about that. Edited to reflect the actual path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there can be some syntax error in your XML config files.

Assuming you are running on a *nix OS, try to validate your config.xml files launching the following command from your Magento root:

`find . -type f -name 'config.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;`

To widen your search you can replace `config.xml` with `*.xml`; note that in that case some false negatives may occur (e.g.: while checking wsdl files).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. All the xml checks out, so while this wasn't the fix it is incredibly helpful!

Comment: Had the exact same issue again, and this was what I needed to find the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Other than an error in a config XML file, it can be an error in `core_config_data` table.
Exact same warning and error messages:

> Warning in lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 443
>
> Fatal error in lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 444

are shown on an instance where someone set by mistake an url in the path field instead of value field, when trying to change the base_url's:
[image]